# centos 6 ftp server -R not working when user create a newfolder on their folder

Tags: ftp

i am used `chown -R it:it /home` for the admin user it for home folder.
under the home folder many user i created like dhaka and folder name dhaka.

```
chmod -R 777 /home 
chmod -R 777 dhaka:it /home/dhaka 
chmod -R 777 dhaka 
it:x:500:500::/home:/sbin/nologin
dhaka:x:505:500::/home/dhaka:/sbin/nologin
```

problem is when user (dhaka) create a new folder on dhaka folder. then that new folder owner only dhaka can read write. and master user (it) only can read but not write.
please help me how do i full access on the users new sub folder on their folder.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add user dhaka in the group of "it".

```
#usermod -a -G it dhaka

#chown dhaka.it /home/dhaka
```

Next need to set sticky group for /home/dhaka directory so new files/directory created in /home/dhaka will have same group ownership which is for /home/dhaka.

```
#chmod g+s /home/dhaka
```

Next you need to modify .bashrc file for dhaka user home directory for default file/directory permission created by dhaka user.

```
echo "umask 002" >> /home/dhaka/.bashrc
```

Umask is used for set file/directory permisison for any newly created by that user.
After completion you can test it with new shell.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. i follow your ans but still not working ftp admin user 'it' cant delete any folder on the user's dhaka subfolder which is created by dhaka user. permission auto change state only owner dhaka can read and write only. please help me how can i get full access on the user's folder and sub folder's by admin user ( it ).

Comment: i am using centos 6 and using vsftpd. is there any other option for this condition. admin user need to full acess every user's folder and subfolder's.

Comment: forget to write command for add user in group so edited my post 
you have to add admin user in all other users group and files/folder should have 775 permission so any user in that group can also delete file.